# Xcode 4 keeps crashing

Tags: ios, xcode

Everytime I try to provision my app onto my iPhone 4, the iPhone screen goes black with the status bar like its about to start the app, but in Xcode I get the spinning rainbow globe and have to force quit every time.

I cleaned the target, cleaned the caches with onyx, and repaired permissions, but its still happening. Please help!!

Comment: Tried rebooting the iPhone or just waiting it out?

Comment: Yeah, started happening a couple hours ago. Rebooted iPhone and Macbook. Neither helped. The simulator causes a similar problem too.

Comment: So, I'm guessing cramming a breakpoint into the very beginning of your `main` routine doesn't work (to determine if it's your code or Xcode)?  If that's the case, I really have no idea. :/

Comment: Just did that, and it worked. And now works without the breakpoint as well. So bizarre -_- Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I have no idea why that would work, but glad it's working nonetheless.  I don't feel like I did anything meriting a proper answer, so maybe just post what you did and accept your own answer so the question doesn't go unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted a breakpoint in the main.m file, and all of a sudden it works. Either after not trying for a while, or by jutting it into working.